# API to create filter for free google app and gmail users

Tags: api, gmail

Is there a way to create a filter in gmail programatically for gmail users as well as for free google app accounts?

It seems that the [e-mail settings API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html#GA_email_filter_main) is only applicable for Google Apps for Business or Education accounts (http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60228).

Answer (score 0):

Aayush.

I would like to know whether anybody knows the answer, because a good gmail filtering app is sorely needed for android users!

I looked everywhere and finally found this:
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.digitalchemy.springclean.gmail&rdid=com.digitalchemy.springclean.gmail&rdot=1#?enroll=yAb5pZ2MYWwmoft_rED3OYt6t0U%3D&purchaseButton=Dw2xBTSDPLCsKHcCnowBY0VcYUU%3D&addInstrument=NyJt6qfLAWzk-RVX01VtYp73FRg%3D

I don't like that it costs 3 dollars and uses 7megs of space. The source is closed, and I'm trying to guess how it does what it does.

This is the most recent link I've found as I try to make my own filtering app and service:
http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/03/oauth-access-to-imapsmtp-in-gmail.html

Comment: From what I can see of SpringClean, it seems to have its own interface - and so acts more like an IMAP client much like Outlook and Thunderbird - and the filter option is probably built into the client, rather than using the gmail filter option.  

What would confirm this is to add a filter to Springclean and see if the same filter also appears on the gmail settings interface.  My guess is that it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears that the API is (as you stated) for Business / Education accounts only, and Google doesn't support Sieve in their IMAP account - http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78761

As I see it - your only option would be to create a custom IMAP client that creates & stores rules on your own server, and then manipulates the email locations "manually" - a rather taxing process if you ask me but doable :)

EDIT:

Here is a little tutorial using Zend_Mail for moving gmail emails via imap
http://www.devcha.com/2010/06/how-to-removemove-messages-using-zend.html